# IIS not responding to the few requests from the client

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7

I am stuck with an issue with IIS 7.0. I need someone's help to find resolution on this, as this is very urgent requirement for us.

Scenario

---

I am trying to host the service in my server (Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.0) and my client is running in the XP machine with IIS 5.1. Few of my request sent from client get successful response and for few request I am getting the below exception in Visual studio when I try to debug.

Exception in Visual studio 2010

---

An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to  This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See the server logs for more details.

When referred to the server event viewer log I got the below events(Application error and System warning) during the above exception.

Under System logs - Warning

---

A process serving application pool 'DefaultAppPool' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '5372'. The data field contains the error number.

Under Application log - Error

---

Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bd0eb
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16559, time stamp: 0x4ba9b802
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000c6df2
Faulting process id: 0x14fc
Faulting application start time: 0x01cbd042562e92c3
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 95f76467-3c35-11e0-a46e-7071bc5cc1ee

From internet I am not able to get the exact solution. Therefore could anyone please help me out from getting resolution for the same that would be really a great help for me. Please let me know if you need more details.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919789

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/09/30/debug-diag-1-2-beta.aspx

Debug Diag should be used for either w3wp crash or hang.